# Particular dates in one table based on dates from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables, one with tasks and the other with some relative data as below:

| Task | Client | Date | Hummer qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Made something a | X1 | 01.02.2022 |  |
| Made something b | X2 | 05.02.2022 |  |
| Made something c | X3 | 05.02.2022 |  |
| Made something d | X2 | 07.02.2022 |  |

So this one represents daily activity for different clients. I need to fill "Hummer qty" column for every day entered for every Client using second table below where there is Dated history of each Client, at which dates quantity of hummers were increased by each Client.

| Client | Date | Hummer qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | 15.03.2021 | 1 |
| X1 | 23.05.2021 | 3 |
| X2 | 08.02.2019 | 1 |
| X2 | 06.02.2022 | 2 |
| X2 | 06.03.2022 | 3 |
| X3 | 16.03.2022 | 1 |

as a result, first table should be as below:

| Task | Client | Date | Hummer qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Made something a | X1 | 01.02.2022 | 3 |
| Made something b | X2 | 05.02.2022 | 1 |
| Made something c | X3 | 05.02.2022 | 0 |
| Made something d | X2 | 07.02.2022 | 2 |

in this case tried to use `Dlookup` with conditions where daily dates >= to history dates + Clients are identical between tables. But it does not work (empty). Simple query returns only first found quantities in history and set it to all the rows of respective client.

Comment: Is this a Microsoft Access question? If so, you should add that as a tag - or, whatever tag represents the _most specific_ technology you are using. Without the correct technology tag(s), the relevant community experts will probably not see your question.

Comment: yes it is access, tag is added. Can someone to propose a way to resolve, please?

Answer (score 0):

You want the qty of History table where History Date is closest to and lower than Tasks Date. This can be done with TOP N correlated subquery.

Consider:

```
SELECT Tasks.*, (SELECT TOP 1 HummerQty FROM History AS H
                 WHERE H.Client=Tasks.Client AND H.Date<Tasks.Date 
                 ORDER BY H.Date DESC) AS HQ 
FROM Tasks;
```

There is no need to commit Qty data to Tasks table as it can be calculated when needed. Also, the query cannot be directly used as source for an update because it is not an editable query. If you really must update:

```
UPDATE Tasks 
SET HummerQty=DLookup("HQ","Query1","Client='" & [Client] & "' AND [Date]=#" & [Date] & "#")
```

If Tasks table has a unique identifier (such as autonumber, which can be easily added), include it in Query1 and then use it in the DLookup WHERE CONDITION argument instead of the compound criteria.

Your data shows dates as international format. This can complicate using date values in comparison expressions. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Comment: Everything works, THANK YOU!!!